# JNIEnv->FindClass returns null OpenJDK 7, returns correctly Oracle JDK 8

Tags: java, c++, jar, packaging, jnienv

```
JavaVM *jvm;
JNIEnv *env;
LoadLibrary(TEXT("jvm.dll"));
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
vm_args.version=JNI_VERSION_1_6;
if (uri != NULL)
{
    vm_args.nOptions=l_paramlines;
}
else 
{
    vm_args.nOptions=l_paramlines-1;
}
vm_args.options=new JavaVMOption[vm_args.nOptions];
int index=0;
char* buffer;
if (uri != NULL)
{
    int bufferLen=512;
    buffer = new char[bufferLen];
    strcpy_s(buffer, bufferLen, "-Dcom.chives.configuri=");
    strcat_s(buffer, bufferLen, uri);
    vm_args.options[index++].optionString = buffer;
}
for (int i=0; i<l_paramlines-1; i++) vm_args.options[index++].optionString=paramlines[i];
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized=false;
jint result=JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, reinterpret_cast<void **>(&env), &vm_args);
if (result!=JNI_OK) return 0;
jclass cls=env->FindClass(paramlines[l_paramlines-1]);
if (cls!=NULL) {
    jmethodID mid=env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    jobjectArray args=env->NewObjectArray(1, env->FindClass("java/lang/String"), NULL);
    env->SetObjectArrayElement(args,0,env->NewStringUTF(game));
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid, args);
}

jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
return 0;
```

is my code where paramlines[l_paramlines-1] is defined to be "Clazz" where there is no package declaration in class Clazz. The variable cls contains NULL structure if I use OpenJDK 7 jvm.dll, but returns a correct initialized struct if I use Oracle JDK 8 jvm.dll.

What's even more interesting is that the OpenJDK 7 jvm.dll works fine if my JAR contains ONLY the class "Clazz", but fails if I include other libraries (such as FasterXML Jackson/Log4j2). I've tried packaging my jars using both Maven on IntelliJ and export as Runnable JAR on Eclipse. Neither work on OpenJDK 7 jvm.dll.

I have to use OpenJDK 7 jvm.dll, so I'm wondering if this is a bug with OpenJDK, or with my JAR packaging.

My META-INF in the various cases:
Eclipse Runnable JAR, works on OpenJDK 7 jvm.dll, contains only class Clazz

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./
Class-Path: .
Rsrc-Main-Class: Clazz
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
```

Eclipse Runnable JAR (extracted classes), fails OpenJDK 7, runs Oracle JDK 8, contains Clazz + libraries

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: .
Main-Class: Clazz
```

IntelliJ Maven (extracted classes), fails OpenJDK 7, runs Oracle JDK 8, contains Clazz + libraries

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_20
Main-Class: Clazz
Built-By: Chives
```

Answer (score 0):

When building with OpenJDK 7 (1.7.0_91) on Linux, and using the JAR file on Windows, JNIEnv->FindClass works as expected (properly finds the main class). This seems to be an Oracle JDK vs OpenJDK issue.

So build with OpenJDK (and run with OpenJDK).